# Prometheus share slaves is set as follows, the status is up, but no data can be searched. Where does my error occur?

Tags: bash, prometheus, federation

> I want to build horizontal extensions, implement a total prometheus,
>   and monitor two child prometheus nodes. For example: Nodes A, B:
>   Monitor Node_exporter and mysql_export data;
>
> The total Prometheus is on the host computer C, and the child nodes are on Hosts A and B respectively.
>
> The master node is configured as follows:

prometheus.yml(host_C):

```
global:

rule_files:
#  - node_rules/zep.test.rules 


scrape_configs:
  - job_name: slaves

    honor_labels: true
    scrape_interval: 1s
    metrics_path: /federate

    params:
      match[]:
         - '{__name__=~"^job:.*"}'
         - '{__job__=~"^job:.*"}'

    static_configs:
      - targets:
         - hostA_ip:9090
         - hostB_ip:9090
```

> The child nodes are configured as follows:

slaves1.yml(host_A):

```
global:

  external_labels:
    slave: 0 


rule_files:

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: myjob_1
    scrape_interval: 1s

    file_sd_configs:
      - files: ['./mytest.json']

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        modulus:       2   
        target_label:  __tmp_hash
        action:        hashmod

      - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
        regex:         ^0$ 
        action:        keep
```

slaves2.yml(host_B):

```
global:

  external_labels:
    slave: 1 


rule_files:

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: myjob_2
    scrape_interval: 1s

    file_sd_configs:
      - files: ['./mytest.json']

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        modulus:       2   
        target_label:  __tmp_hash
        action:        hashmod

      - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
        regex:         ^1$ 
        action:        keep
```

mytest.json:

```
[{
    "targets": [
        "hostA_ip:9100",
        "hostA_ip:9104"
    ],
    "labels": {
        "services": "dba_test"
    }
}]
```

run it :

```
./prometheus --web.listen-address="hostA_ip:9090" --storage.tsdb.path="global_data/" --config.file="prometheus.yml" --web.enable-admin-api
./prometheus --web.listen-address="hostB_ip:9090" --storage.tsdb.path="data1/" --config.file="slave1.yml" --web.enable-admin-api
./prometheus --web.listen-address="hostC_ip:9090" --storage.tsdb.path="data2/" --config.file="slave2.yml" --web.enable-admin-api
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason for this problem is because wildcards do not match. The
>   official website provides ___job____, but the actual use is job.
>
> Specific will also look at the 9090 under the **status** of the **Targets**
>   specific configuration page, not all in accordance with the official
>   to provide configuration